# Filter a Database without if statements in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm currently filtering users in my database with a ton of `if` / `elseif` statements. And hoping there is an easier way. Right now I'm writting if statements for every possible query with the following 5 values:

1. Location
2. Gender
3. Age
4. Birth Month
5. Birth Date

Just to note, I'm using Laravel 5.7

**HTML: Filtering by Pre-Populated Select Dropdowns**

```
<!-- LOCATION -->
<div>
    <select id="location" name="location">
        <option value="">No Preference</option>
        @foreach ($country as $c)
        <option value="{{ $c->country_name }}">{{ $c->country_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<!-- GENDER -->
<div>
    <select id="gender" name="gender">
        <option value="">No Preference</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- AGE -->
<div>
    <select id="age" name="age">
        <option value="">No Preference</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        ETC...
    </select>
</div>
<!-- BIRTH MONTH -->
<div>
    <select id="month" name="month">
        <option value="">No Preference</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        ETC...
    </select>
</div>
<!-- BIRTH DATE -->
<select id="day" name="day">
    <option value="">No Preference</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ETC...
</select>
</div>
<!-- FILTER RESULTS BTN -->
<div>
    <button id="ajaxSubmit">
        Filter Results
    </button>
</div>
```

**JS to filter results**

```
$('#ajaxSubmit').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    var location = $('#location').val();
    var gender = $('#gender').val();
    var age = $('#age').val()
    var month = $('#month').val()
    var day = $('#day').val()

     $.get('/child-sponsorship/filter?location=' + location + '&gender=' + gender + '&age=' + age + '&month=' + month + '&day=' + day, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#kids_results').empty();
        $('#kids_results').html(data);
    });
});
```

**Controller: This works but it's an if statement nightmare**

*PRETTY MUCH MAKING EVERY POSSIBLE VARIATION OF THE FILTERS...*

```
        public function filter(Request $request){ 

        $location = $request->location;
        $gender = $request->gender;
        $age = $request->age;
        $month = $request->month;
        $day = $request->day;

        $country = DB::table('countries')->orderBy('country_name')->get();

        //IF ALL FILTERS ARE EMPTY
        if(empty($location) && empty($gender) && empty($age) && empty($month) && empty($day)){
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('id')->get();
        }//IF ALL FILTER ARE TRUE
        elseif(!empty($location) && !empty($gender) && !empty($age) && !empty($month) && !empty($day)){
           $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')
           ->where('current_country', $location)
           ->where('gender', $gender)
           ->where('age', $age)
           ->where('month', $month)
           ->where('day', $day)
           ->orderby('id')
           ->get(); 
        }//IF LOCATION ONLY IS TRUE
        elseif(empty($gender) && empty($age) && empty($month) && empty($day)){
            $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')
            ->where('current_country', $location)
            ->orderby('id')->get();
        }//IF GENDER ONLY IS TRUE
        elseif(empty($location) && empty($age) && empty($month) && empty($day))

//etc..... 

        //return Response::json($sponsorKid);
        $view = View::make('child-sponsorship.filter_results', compact('sponsorKid'));
        $view = $view->render();
        return $view;
}
```

IS THERE AN EASIER WAY?

I tried using `LIKE` to filter in my controller, but no luck:

```
   $sponsorKid = Kid::query()
   ->where('countries', 'LIKE', "%{$location}%") 
   ->orWhere('gender', 'LIKE', "%{$gender}%")
   ->orWhere('age', 'LIKE', "%{$age}%")
   ->orWhere('month', 'LIKE', "%{$month}%")
   ->orWhere('day', 'LIKE', "%{$day}%")
   ->orderby('id')
   ->get();

        $view = View::make('child-sponsorship.filter_results', compact('sponsorKid'));
        $view = $view->render();
        return $view;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `$sponsorKid = DB::table('kids');` then `if (!empty($location)) $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('current_country', $location);` etc.

Comment: Why on the where you have the query as "%{$location}% instead of "%$location%"?

Comment: @Vidal I was following a tutorial and thats how they were doing it.

Comment: @Vidal I did as you said, and I get the following: `http://xxxxxx.oo/child-sponsorship/filter?location=&gender=&age=12&month=&day= 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @ChrisG Thats what I'm doing now. It works, but your etc.. Is a hundred if statements. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No, my suggestion is different. It has exactly 5 `if`s total: https://pastebin.com/FQkBDhjF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a model for kids table named Kid.php using that you can start a query and do like this:

```
//create a query of Kid model
$sponsorKid = Kid::query();

// add a where clause for location only if location is not empty, 
//otherwise you have the default query
if(!empty($location)) {
    $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('location', $location);
}
// add a where clause for gender only if gender is not empty, 
//otherwise you have the default query, or if this condition and 
//above is true then you will have a query which has 2 wheres 
if(!empty($gender)) {
    $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('gender', $gender);
}

if(!empty($age)) {
    $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('age', $age);
}

if(!empty($month)) {
    $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('age', $age);
}

if(!empty($day)) {
    $sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->where('day', $day);
}

//now that you have a final query pull the records 
$sponsorKid = $sponsorKid->orderBy('id')->get();

$view = View::make('child-sponsorship.filter_results', compact('sponsorKid'));
    $view = $view->render();
    return $view;
```

Answer (score 3):

try to used [conditional-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses)

**when** method of query builder

```
 $sponsorKid = Kid::when($location,function($q,$location) {
     return  $q->where('countries', 'LIKE', "%."$location."%") 
   })->when($gender,function($q,$gender) {
      return  $q->orWhere('gender', 'LIKE', "%".$gender."%")
   })->when($age,function($q,$age) {
      return  $q->orWhere('age', 'LIKE', "%".$age."%")
   })->when($month,function($q,$month) { 
      return $q->orWhere('month', 'LIKE', "%".$month."%")
   })->when($day,function($q,$day) {
      return $q->orWhere('day', 'LIKE', "%".$day."%")
   })->orderby('id')
   ->get();
```

Comment: This was working, but probably best for a search of all conditions rather than filtering out the exact match. Very helpful though and will use in the future. Thank you!